# Comparing Diagnostic Attributes in a Meta-Analysis of Diagnostic Performance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, meta-analysis

I'm currently conducting a meta-analysis in which I compare the diagnostic performance of two different methods. All the studies in the analysis employ the same reference standard. The pooled sensitivity, specificity, negative likelihood ratio (NLR), positive likelihood ratio (PLR), and diagnostic odds ratio (DOR) for each study are already available.

What I need guidance on is how to compare these test performances. Should I implement hypothesis testing, or should my conclusions be drawn solely based on the lack of overlap of the confidence intervals?

Comment: How many tests in total? 2 or 3? From your description, it is a bit ambiguous if you have 2 or 3 tests (e.g., A vs reference standard, or A vs reference standard and B vs reference standard, and then you want to compared A vs B indirectly).

Comment: I have 2 tests studied against the same reference standard. And I want to compare them indirectly.

Comment: Check these materials. They have an example comparing two tests (against the same reference standard)     https://training.cochrane.org/10s1-supplementary-material-code-undertaking-meta-analysis